# How can I set the firewall rules on Iptables without them getting deleted?

Tags: security, tails, firewall

I am sending command line commands to the Iptables. Once I set these rules I connect to my router. on connecting all the rules I just add is removed and only the original firewall rules that tails has added is present. I can not save and restore the rules as I am using a DVD. How can I send commands to Iptables and make them stay without getting deleted after I have connected to the router? I can added rules after the connection is made but I would like to have the firewall rules set before the connection.

Comment: You can't, you'd be best building a custom Tails image. It's designed not to persist. https://tails.boum.org/contribute/customize/ or if you don't mind enabling root access and manually editing a file every time you use Tails, you could add them to the ferm config at `/etc/ferm/ferm.conf`, which is what configures `iptables` on Tails.